# Data Subsetting

Tags: r, subset, sample, random-seed

Can you help me find a better way to do this in r-studio?
Select 50% of the mtcars dataset randomly without replacement and name it mtcars 50.

To find: From mtcars50 dataset, write a command to select only observations with hp greater than 150?

```
subset(mtcars50, mtcars50$hp>150)
```

I already tried doing the following:

```
sample_frac(mtcars, 0.50, replace = FALSE) 
#To select 50% of the mtcars dataset

mtcars50<-sample_frac(mtcars, 0.50, replace = FALSE)
```

I'm not sure if this is correct but I did this to name the new dataset.

But when I run the code below to select only observations with hp greater than 150 from mtcars50 dataset, some variables in its output is not included in mtcars50 dataset. I assumed that the code I have run made another subset and from there, it selected the observations.

```
subset(mtcars50, mtcars50$hp>150)
```

I'm sorry if this is kinda confusing. But I hope you can help me with my problem. Thank you so much.

```
sample_frac(mtcars, 0.50, replace = FALSE)
mtcars50<-sample_frac(mtcars, 0.50, replace = FALSE)
mtcars50<-sample_frac(mtcars, 0.50, replace = FALSE)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please try to edit your post to clearly show the code you are running (using three consecutive backticks), what output you get, and what output you are hoping for? And please do not show code or results of the output as images -- unless it is an image, of course.

Comment: I'm unclear what your question is. In the top-part of the second image it seems that all listed cars are appropriately above 150 hp and they are a sampled fraction from the full mtcars dataset. How did you expect the results for `subset(mtcars50, mtcars50$hp>150)` to look?

Comment: *"some variables in its output is not included in mtcars50 dataset"* - which variables do you think are missing? I count row names + 11 variables in all of the output you show. The total width of the output is different because some of the subsets don't have row names that are quite as long as others.

Comment: Hi welcome to SO! I got your problem.  Actually you are getting different results when you sample and when you store it because R has picked different random seed each time.  See my answer for explanation

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

I got it, the problem you're facing because you are working on different random sample each time.  Set the random seed and you won't face this issue.  See

```
set.seed(1)
sample_frac(mtcars, 0.50, replace = FALSE) 

                  mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Pontiac Firebird 19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
Hornet 4 Drive   21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Duster 360       14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
Mazda RX4        21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag    21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
AMC Javelin      15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
Merc 280C        17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
Merc 450SLC      15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
Fiat 128         32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
Honda Civic      30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
Ford Pantera L   15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
Toyota Corona    21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
Merc 280         19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
Volvo 142E       21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
Toyota Corolla   33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
Ferrari Dino     19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6

# now filtering part

set.seed(1)

mtcars50<-sample_frac(mtcars, 0.50, replace = FALSE)

subset(mtcars50, mtcars50$hp>150)

                  mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Pontiac Firebird 19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
Duster 360       14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
Merc 450SLC      15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
Ford Pantera L   15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
Ferrari Dino     19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
```

**However, without setting the seed you may get different datasets you view and that you store.**  See

```
> sample_frac(mtcars, 0.50, replace = FALSE) 
                    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Merc 230           22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
Cadillac Fleetwood 10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
Toyota Corona      21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout  18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Volvo 142E         21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
Pontiac Firebird   19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
Merc 450SLC        15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
Ford Pantera L     15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
Porsche 914-2      26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
Mazda RX4 Wag      21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Merc 280           19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
Merc 450SE         16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
Maserati Bora      15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
Mazda RX4          21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710         22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Valiant            18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1


> mtcars50<-sample_frac(mtcars, 0.50, replace = FALSE)
> subset(mtcars50, mtcars50$hp>150)
                    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Cadillac Fleetwood 10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
Merc 450SE         16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
Ferrari Dino       19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
Pontiac Firebird   19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
Camaro Z28         13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
Duster 360         14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
Maserati Bora      15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
```

**Note** that `Hornet sportabout` having hp = 175 is not present in subset.

Hope this clears the doubt